# Read multiple gz files in Spark to treat mutliple data frames

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to read multiple files in Spark, so I tried to do that :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
path_5 = cos.url('*.gz', 'mounts381273cf3e1ee4647976ff6a7f5334537')

# spark is an existing SparkSession
df1 = spark.read.json(path_5)
# Displays the content of the DataFrame to stdout
df1.show()
```

When I do :

```
df1.createOrReplaceTempView ("table1")
df3 = spark.sql("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM table1").show()
```

The result obtained is 79784.

I have two gz files in that directory and I did the same manipulation :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
path_5 = cos.url('20160515000523_49559317672952246664631132266050590905816465503319752754-49559317672952246664631133026940039290527012843121803314.gz', 'mounts381273cf3e1ee4647976ff6a7f5334537')
path_6 = cos.url('20160515001138_49559317698308193955360450873593063506777935176037040194-49559317698308193955360451613760314417474117784886575170.gz', 'mounts381273cf3e1ee4647976ff6a7f5334537')
```

and when I count both, the result is 79784 for the first one and 40024 for the second one.

So when I try to treat both files with the command

```
path_5 = cos.url('*.gz', 'mounts381273cf3e1ee4647976ff6a7f5334537')
```

I obtain the same result than for the first file, so I think I'm wrong when I use this command.

Anyone has an idea to treat these files in one time and obtain the whole dataframe ?

Thanks!!

Comment: If all the .gz files are under the same directory , you need to provide the parent directory path , spark automatically figure out all the .gz inside it.

Comment: @user8371915 Sorry I didn't specify what I wrote before this line : `cos = ibmos2spark.CloudObjectStorage(sc, credentials, configuration_name)`